# Show recipe name if all of its ingredients are already given

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with this structure:

**Recipe**

id | recipe_name

**Ingredients**

id | ingredients_name

**Relationship**

rid | recipe_id | ingredients_id

Example i search for recipe's with an ingredient of "chicken" and "mayonnaise" then it will display all the recipe's having this two ingredients. i already get the code for that:

```
SELECT * from recipe r
INNER JOIN relationship ri on r.id=ri.recipe_id
INNER JOIN ingredients i on i.id=ri.ingredients_id
WHERE i.ingredients_name IN ('chicken','mayonnaise')
GROUP BY r.id
```

But what I want is that when a recipe contains only chicken and mayonnaise as its ingredients, it must display on a separate result. How can i do that?

Comment: "separate result"? As another column?

Comment: Can you provide an example table of the result?

Comment: BTW: The query you provide will give you the recipe that contains at least on of 'chicken' or 'mayonnaise' not the recipes having this two ingredients as you said.

Comment: i need to display it using another query not as separated column coz the query i posted like MGA7 had said is only displaying recipe's having an ingredient of chicken and mayonnaise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a HAVING clause - like so:

```
SELECT * from recipe r
INNER JOIN relationship ri on r.id=ri.recipe_id
INNER JOIN ingredients i on i.id=ri.ingredients_id
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ingredients_name)=2 AND
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when i.ingredients_name IN ('chicken','mayonnaise') 
                           then i.ingredients_name end)=2
```

(Note: this will return recipes that *only* include both chicken and mayonnaise, and no other ingredients. To return recipes that include both chicken and mayonnaise, but that could also include other ingredients, remove the `COUNT(DISTINCT case` condition and reinstate the `WHERE` clause.)

Comment: it shows an error when i tried it on my server... it shows 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY r.id LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: @rjx44: My query doesn't include `LIMIT 0, 30` - try running my query, unmodified.

Comment: i already tested it unmodified but it returns this error :            #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: this is the query response by sql : 
SELECT *
FROM recipe r
INNER JOIN relationship ri ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
INNER JOIN ingredients i ON i.id = ri.ingredients_id
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT i.ingredients ) =2
AND COUNT( DISTINCT
CASE WHEN i.ingredients
IN (
'Chicken', 'Mayonnaise'
)
THEN i.ingredients
END ) =2
GROUP BY r.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
and it shows the same error again...

Comment: @rjx44: I had the `GROUP BY` clause in the wrong place - I have now corrected it. The query should work now.

Answer (score 1):

we need to skip all the recipes which have ingredients other than chicken and mayonnaise, so something like below should work:

```
SELECT * from recipe r
INNER JOIN relationship ri on r.id=ri.recipe_id
INNER JOIN ingredients i on i.id=ri.ingredients_id
WHERE i.ingredients_name IN ('chicken','mayonnaise')
and r.id not in (select r.id from recipe r
INNER JOIN relationship ri on r.id=ri.recipe_id
INNER JOIN ingredients i on i.id=ri.ingredients_id
WHERE i.ingredients_name not IN ('chicken','mayonnaise'))
```

Comment: it is not working the way i wanted it to be, the query display recipe's that contains this two but not the recipe's with exact ingredients as given.. but thanks for helping me, you're help is greatly appreciated.. but if you can help me more I'll be very glad to..

Comment: my bad.. just change the line: and **ri**.id not in (select r.id from recipe r **to** and **r**.id not in (select r.id from recipe r