# I want to display the recipe containing the given ingredient but having other ingredients too

Tags: mysql, sql

In relation to my first question ["Show recipe name if all of its ingredients are already given"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257151/show-recipe-name-if-all-of-its-ingredients-are-already-given)

My First question asks about displaying the recipe when all of its ingredients are given out, The next thing is somehow the same thing as the first one but it needs to display the recipe( having the given ingredients like the first one) and having as well some ingredients in able for this recipe to be completed. sorry for my bad english. I hope you know what i mean with this.

Comment: Duplicate of [Show recipe name if all of its ingredients are already given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257151/show-recipe-name-if-all-of-its-ingredients-are-already-given), same user.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta this is not a duplicate one, the result i wanted from this question is not the same as the first one i've questioned.. sorry for my bad english.. can you help me with this? you're help is gladly appreciated..

Comment: What's the difference between your two questions, rjx44?

Comment: @simchona I'm sorry for my question but what i mean with this second question is the opposite one of my first question.. really need help here.. :-(

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta thank you for your response. I want to display the recipe's that contains the given ingredients but need's another ingredient to complete that recipe.. basically it is a suggestive type from the first question i asked before..

Comment: @simchona ok i will reverse it down.. thank you so much

Comment: thanks @BrandonMoore. can you help me with this?. ;( (:|

Comment: @rjx44 I'm thinking about it... my first choice would be to handle this in the client code (php, java, or .net, or whatever you're using).  I'll post one idea in a second though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to my answer (now corrected) to the first question - this should return all recipes that contain *all* of the specified ingredients, but *also* require additional ingredients:

```
SELECT r.* from recipe r
INNER JOIN relationship ri on r.id=ri.recipe_id
INNER JOIN ingredients i on i.id=ri.ingredients_id
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.ingredients_name)>2 AND
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when i.ingredients_name IN ('chicken','mayonnaise') 
                           then i.ingredients_name end)=2
```

Comment: thnx for the reply. But your query displays a zero result.

Comment: wow. that was great. it worked. Thank you so much for the help... A TWO THUMBS UP!! a great relief for me.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In order to look up a list of recipes based on a list of ingredients, where a recipe must have those ingredients but could also have more, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT R.name
FROM Recipe R, Ingredients I, Relationship Rel
WHERE I.ingredients_name = 'Chicken' AND Rel.ingredients_id = I.id AND 
   Rel.recipe_id=R.id

INTERSECT

SELECT R.name
FROM Recipe R, Ingredients I, Relationship Rel
WHERE I.ingredients_name = 'Mayo' AND Rel.ingredients_id = I.id AND 
   Rel.recipe_id=R.id
```

What this is doing is finding all of the recipes where "Chicken" is an ingredient, and intersecting it with all of the recipes where "Mayo" is an ingredient. This gives you the recipes where "Chicken" and "Mayo" are *both* ingredients for a given recipe.

---

On second thought, MySQL doesn't have the INTERSECT keyword. In that case, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.name FROM Recipe R
INNER JOIN (SELECT R.name
            FROM Recipe R, Ingredients I, Relationship Rel
            WHERE I.ingredients_name = 'Chicken' AND Rel.ingredients_id = I.id AND 
              Rel.recipe_id=R.id) as recipeA
INNER JOIN (SELECT R.name
            FROM Recipe R, Ingredients I, Relationship Rel
            WHERE I.ingredients_name = 'Mayo' AND Rel.ingredients_id = I.id AND 
               Rel.recipe_id=R.id) as recipeB
```

Comment: +1 - It seems like there should still be something simpler but I'm not sure that there is.

Comment: @BrandonMoore I was thinking maybe a JOIN might be more helpful? But this way (albeit slow) is relatively easy to understand conceptually. I'll upvote you if you have a simpler version

Comment: it cause me an error here... :-( #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECT SELECT R.name FROM Recipe R, Ingredients I, Relationship Rel WHERE ' at line 6

Comment: @rjx44 Try now? I used a keyword that wasn't in MySQL by mistake

Comment: I would definitely create a view called something like vwRecipe_Ingredients that joins the tables together first, and then reference that view.  It will make the sql much more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @BrandonMoore I see where you're coming from, definitely. I don't have much experience in MySQL Views, though, so I'm afraid I can't go much further

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias - it produces this error.

Comment: rjx44 Edited again; please try. In terms of maintainability, though, I think you should spend some time looking at @BrandonMoore's ideas.

Comment: It returns an empty result. but thanks for the help. I'll try to do some research about what @BrandonMoore had said..

Answer (score 0):

I think simchona may be onto something good but you will obviously have to generate code in a loop that makes a select clause for each ingredient.

One other way some people have tackled similar problems is to aggregate a column into a single string and test against that.  I think there are pros and cons to both ways in regard to both performance and maintainability.  A good place to start for deciding how to concatenate the strings if you want to look into this method is http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Another option would be to create a stored procedure and use some TSQL in a loop to make a list of matching items... definitely the last option I would normally choose but depending on how good of performance you need this could be a viable route to take.

Comment: It's a little bit complicating coz I am just a newbie when it comes to mysql but I will try to study about that and really thanks for the help.. :-)

Comment: @rjx44 Yep, this certainly isn't an easy problem even for most who aren't beginners.

Comment: @rjx44 This is one I'd really like to know a better answer for myself.  Check back in a few days if you still need help b/c after 2 days Stack Overflow will let me put a bounty on this question to attract more people to it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope many would be interested with this, I really need to have this work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @rjx44 As much as I appreciate having my post being marked the answer, you should probably click the checkmark again to unmark it if you want other people to come and hopefuly offer better answers.

Answer (score 0):

i think the following query will fulfill the requirement:

```
SELECT r.recipe_name from recipe r
INNER JOIN relationship ri on r.id=ri.recipe_id
INNER JOIN ingredients i on i.id=ri.ingredients_id
where i.ingredients_name IN ('chicken','mayonnaise')
GROUP BY r.recipe_name
HAVING COUNT(i.ingredients_name) > 1
```